# Implement dynamic variable in trackingpixel

Tags: php, variables

I have to implement a dynamic variable in a trackingpixel for an affiliate program. We have worked with this pixel before, but now we need to define currency as a dynamic variable, because we have a multi currency webshop (EUR, GBP).

The trackingpixel is as follows:

```
<?php
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$total = $order->getData('grand_total');
?>

<img src="http://domain.com/?&productID=&conversionType=sale&transactionID=<?php echo $this->getOrderId()?>&transactionAmount=<?= $total ?&currency=VARIABEL" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

But now I need to implement the code snippet that fetches the currency code into the pixel.

I know the co snippet looks like this:

```
$currencyCode = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
```

Can someone help me implement this into the pixel?

Comment: Do you need this? `<img src="http://domain.com/?&productID=&conversionType=sale&transactionID=<?php echo $this->getOrderId(); ?>&transactionAmount=<?php echo $total ?>&currency=<?php echo $order->getOrderCurrencyCode(); ?>" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />`

Comment: This is what I meant yeah. So I don't have to implement it in the part above? I will just check if this works:)